# What causes "requires valid signature" error when calling FQL from javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-fql

My site uses FQL called from javascript as such:

```
FB.api({
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT uid, name, first_name, pic_big, pic, third_party_id from user where uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY name'
},
function(response) {
    if( response.error_msg ) {            
        alert("Sorry!  Something went wrong loading your Facebook friends:"+response.error_msg);
        return;
    }
    process_friends(response);
});
```

}

They get here after a normal `FB.login()` call.  This is working fine for most users.  But some users (or user sessions at least) consistently get the "requires valid signature" error and can't get past this, even after `FB.login()`'ing in again.

What does that error really mean?  I'm guessing the oauth token is invalid?  But the token came from within the javascript SDK -- I never touched it, and didn't make the signature.  Could the user be in an inconsistent login state?  Insufficient app privileges?  Some strange cookie setting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does mean that you need a valid access token.

**EDIT:** A better link to the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/

Comment: Great.  But why would their own code have an invalid token when they got it themselves?

Comment: I believe that if you're logged into facebook you have an access token.  They expire after a certain amount of time and you have to check the validity of the token when you make a call.  However, I'm not sure why you would get the expired token after a Login unless somehow the old token is hashed.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/   You can see on that page: In addition to the access token (the access_token parameter), the response contains the number of seconds until the token expires (the expires parameter). Once the token expires, you will need to re-run the steps above to generate a new code and access_token, although if the user has already authorized your app, they will not be prompted to do so again.

Comment: If your app needs an access token with an infinite expiry time (perhaps to take actions on the user's behalf after they are not using your app), you can request the offline_access permission.